# Where should I create uploads folder and place upload.php while implementing ng2 file upload in localhost:4200

Tags: php, angular, file-upload

I have implemented ng2 file upload on my server.

It asks for an API URL and I have provided it. Everything works online as expected. But I want to run it locally for further implementation.

This is my upload api URL:

```
const URL = 'http://example.com/v8/products-api/upload2.php';
```

In upload2.php  the path is given as `$path = 'uploads/';`.

My question is, where shall I create this folder and where shall I place this php file ?

I am unable to upload a file to server from `http:localhost:4200` as it gives the following error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://funiks.com/adminv8/products-api/upload2.php. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.`

My php includes `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

Answer (score 0):

I'm no PHP expert, so I can't attest to the CORS configuration of your server. But reading the error you're getting it looks like you can't use a wildcard, so why not try setting your headers like so...

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200', false);`

Also you could try using the Angular `Jsonp` library rather than the `Http`. The functions will stay exactly the same, however you do open up some security concerns by doing so...

(P.S. If you use the `Jsonp` library, just add `&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK` to the end of your API url)